# Is it possible to Split an ehcache config file?

Tags: spring, configuration, ehcache

I'm writing a jar intended to be used with Spring and Ehcache.  Spring requires that there be a cache defined for each element, so I was planning to have an Ehcache defined for the jar, preferably as a resource in the jar that could be imported into the primary Ehcache configuration for the app.  However, my reading of the [example Ehcache config file](http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xml) and my Google searches have not turned up any way to import a sub Ehcache config file.

Is there a way to import a sub Ehcache config file, or is there some other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Related (possible dup?): [Is it possible to use multiple ehcache.xml (in different projects, same war)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8834993/16487)

Answer (score 1):

What I did to do something similar (replace some placeholders in my Ehcache xml file - a import statement is more or less a placeholder if you will) is to extend (more or less copy to be honest) from Springs [`EhCacheManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.html) and create the final Ehcache xml config file on the fly.

For creating the  `CacheManager` instance in `afterPropertiesSet()` you just hand over a `InputStream` which points to your config.

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws IOException, CacheException {
    if (this.configLocation != null) {
        InputStreamSource finalConfig = new YourResourceWrapper(this.configLocation); // put your custom logic here
        InputStream is = finalConfig.getInputStream();
        try {
            this.cacheManager = (this.shared ? CacheManager.create(is) : new CacheManager(is));
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        }
    } else {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

For my filtering stuff I internally used a `ByteArrayResource` to keep the final config.

```
data = IOUtils.toString(source.getInputStream()); // get the original config (configLocation) as string
// do your string manipulation here
Resource finalConfigResource =  new ByteArrayResource(data.getBytes());
```

For "real" templating one could also think of using a real template engine like FreeMarker (which Spring has support for) to do more fancy stuff.